# UV unwrapping spiral sphere to show geometric accurate 2D plane

Tags: uv

I am trying to unwrap a sphere I made using the UV-sphere mesh and adding a SimpleDeform modifier and twisting it along the Z-axis. When trying to unwrap it in the uv viewer it only shows up as either very strange or overly simple combinations, and not as the realistic geometric shape. I am trying to achieve a result similar to what would happen if you took a paper model and unfolded it into a 2D plane, in order to get two long pieces you could sew back together in order to make a sphere. Other variants of unwrap yield even weirder results.

I realize this is quite a simple problem, and so I hope there is a simple solution. I am quite new to blender, so sorry if anything was wrongly worded. Any answer is appreciated!

[image: axis run along the edges on both sides, and regular unwrap is used]

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions and I think you forgot to mention something:
You removed large strips of UVsphere from pole to pole. When I do that, it looks like your picture.
It would be helpful to upload the model to [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all:**

I tried to follow your instructions and I think you forgot to mention something:
You removed large strips of UVsphere from pole to pole. When I do that, it looks like your picture.
It would be helpful to upload the model to [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/).

## About UVunwrap

UV unwrap tries to make the shapes simple and it also tries to keep the rctangles kind of square.
Because of this, the shape of the uvunwrap will not resemble your deformations of the mesh very well.

## Modifier does not affect results of UV unwrap

You may find that the result of all unwrap operations remains the same whether the modifier is turned on or not - you can also delete the modifier completely, the result of UVunwrap remains the same.

## Solution: Apply Modifier before UV unwrapping

However, you can achieve other results by applying the modifier:

1. Exit the edit mode (if you are currently in it) and switch to the object mode.
2. On the right side of the modifier's header, select the modifier's "Apply" option from the drop-down menu. This will make the effect permanent.
3. If you now UV unwrap again, results will be different and maybe more of what you expected.
   [image: UV unwrap after applying Modifier]
   [image]

## Finetuning

The shape in the UV Editor is just a 2D point mesh. Points can be selected, moved, scaled etc. like in other Blender Editors, so feel free to finetune the results to your further likings.

Comment: Hi! That did indeed do it! I didn't realise that applying the modifier changed the way UV is shown. Thank you so much for the help, and sorry for the lacking info in the original question. Life saver!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to hear that it worked for you.